# TypeError Subcategory is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am creating the simplest schema ever yet I am getting this annoying error and am not sure why. Perhaps I just need a fresh pair of eyes to see the obvious error. The error I am getting is :

> TypeError Subcategory is not a constructor

I create all my schemas like this and haven't had an issue before.

My mongoose schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const subcategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255
  }
});

const Subcategory = mongoose.model("Subcategory", subcategorySchema);

module.exports = Subcategory;
```

Controller:

```
const { Subcategory } = require("../models/subcategoryModel");

// add subcategory
exports.postSubcategory = async (req, res) => {
  let subcategory = new Subcategory({
    name: req.body.name
  });
  subcategory = await subcategory.save();
  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    data: {
      data: subcategory
    }
  });
};
```

Routes:

```
const express = require("express");
const subcategoryController = require("../controllers/subcategoryController");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", subcategoryController.getSubcategories);
router.post("/", subcategoryController.postSubcategory);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are exporting `Subcategory` like this:

```
module.exports = Subcategory;
```

You need to import it like the following:

```
const Subcategory = require("../models/subcategoryModel");
```